# Make a Method Which Generates the x and y values of Another Given Function

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, runnable, callable

I have just started to learn about Java `Runnable`s and I have heard of `Callable`s. However, I am very much struggling with this problem. I would like to make a method which takes a function as an argument (whether that be as a `Callable`, a `Runnable`, or something else, as long as I can simply call the function as `coolNewFunction(() -> otherFunction(), 100)` or some similar simple way) and the method would return an array of the returned values of the `otherFunction`. For example, say I defined the function

```
public static int square(int x){

    return x * x;

}
```

I could then do something along the lines of:

```
coolNewFunction(() -> square(), 100)
```

And this would return an array of the first 100 numbers and their squares (i.e. `{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}...}`). Now right off the bat I know that the `lambda () -> square()` wouldn't work because `square` has to be passed a value. I though of creating an array of 100 `Runnable`s each of which has the next argument for `square`, but still the method `run()` doesn't return anything. **So, long story short, what would a method look like which evaluates another function which is given as an argument like `square` at different x values and returns an array of that evaluation?** Also, preferably I don't want to start any new threads although if this is the only way that this can be achieved than that is okay. Finally, I don't want to have to implement the `square` (or other) function in a special way (preferably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
public int[][] fn2Array(Function<Integer, Integer> fn, int x) {
    int[][] result = new int[x][2];
    for (int i; i < x; i++) {
        result[i][0]=i+1;
        result[i][1]=fn.apply(i+1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Consider `IntUnaryOperator` instead of `Function<Integer, Integer>`, it avoids unnecessary boxing.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you don't mind if I don't use an `Array`, but I will use your `square` method

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> lotsOfSquares(int limit) {

    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1,limit)                         // Creates a stream of 1, 2, 3, ... limit
                    .boxed()                                      //  Boxes int to Integer. 
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i,             // Collects the numbers, i->i generates the map key
                                              i -> square(i));    // Generates the map value
}
```

This will give you a map containing `{1=1, 2=4, 3=9, ... , 99=9801, 100=10000}`.

You should probably add some validation on `limit`.

Update:

```
public <T> Map<Integer, T> lotsOfResults(int limit, Function<Integer, T> f) {

    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1,limit)                        
                    .boxed()                                      
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i,             
                                              i -> f.apply(i));    
}
```

Now, you can call `lotsOfResults(100, i -> square(i))`

Note that `T` is the return type of `f` -- in case you get tired of squaring.

Comment: I would like to pass square as an argument. Here each time I would have to change out what method I am using (to something else like sin, cos, etc.), so how would I have square as an argument?